# Flutter, scroll, pinch and zoom large image

Tags: image, zooming, flutter

I need to show a large image (or pdf) that the user can then scroll around and pinch & zoom.

In iOS / Android, I'd just show it in a WebView.
Note: the file to display is from the filesystem (an asset), not from the internet.

Is there a way of doing this in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the only thing that you can do is to use this plugin:

https://github.com/dart-flitter/flutter_webview_plugin

It is not very customizable, but it should work for simple use cases.

PS. The zoom actually doesn't work and there is also another similar library:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_web_view

Comment: Thanks, I ended up writing my own webview plugin with pinch and zoom.

Comment: please share the plugin , if you are ok with it. thank you